# Directing websockets to same port as http connection through nginx/apache

Tags: apache, nginx, websocket

I have the following model that i drew below:

[image]

I have a number of processes running on the server. I want nginx or apache to direct the incoming clients through port 80 to one of the server processes to handle the requests. However each connection also establishes a websocket connection to the same process. This is currently initiated from the client side within javascript. At the moment for testing purposes I pass the port within the html rendered on the client. The client then takes this port and estabilishes a websocket connection to the same port that handled its request.

Moving forward to an nginx or apache envionment would it be possible not to pass the port value to the client and have nginx or apache know where it directed the incoming client and use the same port for the websocket connection? 
This would have the benefit on not opening all the server ports 8000, 8001, 8002 in the diagram below to the public.